2 different interpretations of the same sentence
There seems to be 2 ways of interpreting this sentence:
身を護るためとはいえ、俺がこの手で殺めたんだ
Since in the comics I'm reading, there was a group of three people against lions, I think it can be either, to protect our body, as in not to get killed, but also although they were protecting themseleves
Is there some way to disambiguate it? I'm having trouble understanding who is the subject of 身を護る here

I think you should pay attention to ため=for. It says Although (X was) for protecting oneself, I killed them, then X is naturally the killing and hence the subject of protecting is I.

There is no action here that the lions were doing in order to (ため) 身を護る. 「身を守るためとはいえ」 (although it was to defend myself) implies that 殺めた was done for that sake. If it were the lions defending themselves it would be something like 「ただ身を護ろうとしていただけなのに俺がこの手で殺めたんだ」
